# Spring Boot: Purpose of spring-starter-web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm new to the `Spring` ecosystem and lot of things are quite confusing. I have a web-project with the following starter packs: `spring-boot-starter-jersey` and `spring-boot-starter-jetty`. This boots up a Jetty server with Jersey servlet. Which is good. But it doesn't serve static content. So, I installed `spring-boot-starter-web` and this serves all the static resources under `resources/static`. But I don't understand how. It seems overkill to install a package just to serve static-content. If it's a non-spring project, I'd use Jetty to create a new servlet and link up a `base resource path`. But I'm not exactly sure how to achieve this without using `spring-starter-web`.

So, does `spring-starter-web` have any additional value in my project setup (excluding static resource serving)?

How can I server static resources using only `Jetty` without the `starter-web`?

Answer (score 0):

This Spring Boot Starter Web uses Spring MVC, REST and Tomcat as a default embedded server, so you will need to adjust it to replace it with Jetty. You can do that with the following:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> </dependency> <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

The `spring-boot-starter-web` transitively depends on the following:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
org.springframework:spring-web
org.springframework:spring-webmvc
```

Additionally, the `spring-boot-starter-web` auto-configures the following features that are usually required for web development:

- Dispatcher Servlet
- Error Page
- Web JARs for managing the static dependencies
- Embedded servlet container

Having said all that unless you really want to have finer-grained control over the dependencies on your project I would suggest you using `spring-boot-starter-web` because it saves you from a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I've added the exclusions, just didn't mention them in the question. So, I'm using jetty as the embedded servlet container and Jersey as the dispatcher servlet. The only purpose I see in your list for starter-web is to serve my static content. Which I find it overkill.

Comment: The thing is that configuring Spring to serve static content on your own might not be that easy. You can try to look into https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources and https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot to understand which are the relevant beans at stake, but my wild guess is that it will not be that simple.